# Show confirmation and redirection on same time

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have few questions,

1. I want to show the alert window on my Update record button click.But
   i already i have `onClientClick` event set for button.So is there
   any other way to do that.
2. Using `Response.Write()` can i do some thing which is show me
   message of updation as well as redirect to my other page.
3. Can i use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` methode to do that
   functionality? and how

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by handling  the client and server events :)

thanks for all response.

Answer (score 1):

use `OnClientClick` and `confirm()` js

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure You Want to Update?')" />
```

Comment: Hi Ishan,as i mention,i already have the Validation mathod for the `onClientClick`.can you suggest me any different ways using the `ClientScript`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return  Validate()" />

<script>
function Validate()
{
    //do validation here
    if(notPassValidation) 
    {
          alert(validationMessage);
          return false;
    }
    //valifation passed, do confirmation
    if(!confirm('Are You Sure You Want to Update?') )
    {
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
         return true;
    }

}

</script>
```